# Write Hive Table Data into a file in Json Format

Tags: json, jar, hive, brickhouse

I am trying to write Hive table data into an external file in Json format.

```
({"column_name_1: column_value_1", "column_name_2: column_value_2"}).
```

Can serde do that? I read serde only reads data in json format but not write it back.

I read about [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) but I am not able to add the jar correctly.

I followed all the steps in the documentation in the link provided above but it fails. Am I doing this right?

```
add jar /root/brickhouse/target/brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
/root/brickhouse/target/brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exist
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: /root/brickhouse/target/brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To add Jar to **HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH** of HiveServer2:

  1. Copy the brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar files to the host on which HiveServer2 is running. Create the follows directory **/usr/share/hivejar** and save here the JAR.
  2. Modify the **hive-site.xml** Executing the following commands on terminal:

     ```
     sudo vi /etc/alternatives/hive-conf/hive-site.xml:

     <property>
     <name>hive.metadata.export.location</name>
     <value>export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/usr/share/hivejar</value>
     </property>
     ```
  3. Restart the Hive service. If the Hive Auxiliary Jars Directory property is configured but the directory does not exist, HiveServer2 will not start.
- To Check ENV Variables of Hive Execute the following commands on terminal:

  ```
  hive 
  hive> set -v;
  hive> quit;
  ```
- Execute the following commands on terminal (under **/usr/share/hivejar** ):

  ```
  hive

  hive> add jar brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
  hive> quit;
  ```

Comment: Thanks, one more question: how do I "Source the UDF declarations defined in src/main/resource/brickhouse.hql" ?

Comment: Once you add the jar create a temporary function as: CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION to_json AS 'brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF';